# Package 'samba' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sudo, apt-get, samba

I am trying to run the code below:

```
shaliya@achala:~$ sudo apt-get install samba

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package samba is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

However, I am getting this error:

> E: Package 'samba' has no installation candidate

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your question would be better placed in Unix&Linux, SuperUser or maybe even askubuntu.com. But you need to read their guidelines on how to ask questions. At the very least, you need to specify the distribution and version. Sharing your `/etc/apt/sources` would be nice too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run those commands below before trying to install samba:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And just in case: `sudo apt-get autoremove samba`

and run: `sudo apt-get install samba`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in ubuntu 20.04, this worked fine for me.
Execute these
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install

then  -Ubuntu Software Center edit the  Software Sources and made these changes.

[image]

Later execute the below commands

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
 sudo apt-get install your-package-name
```